# New action in Grails controller errors out

Tags: grails

I'm new to groovy & grails so this may be silly.

But I have a very simple hello world app, the index action works fine, but I tried to add a new action `ok` and it errors out when rebuilding.

My controller is very simple

```
class AggregatorController {

    def index() {
        render "hello world 2222"
    }

    def ok() {
         render "no"
    }
}
```

This is the error I get:

org.grails.core.exceptions.GrailsRuntimeException: Error instantiated artefact class [class nba.AggregatorController] of type [class org.grails.core.DefaultGrailsControllerClass]: InvocationTargetException

And inside of the traceback I see this:

Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: nba.AggregatorController.ok()Ljava/lang/Object;

If I delete the ok method everything works great

Comment: Ok ! I just ran `grails clean` and then re-ran grails and its working now, but I would like to understand why that happened if possible, thanks

Comment: check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4567986/what-does-the-grails-clean-script-actually-do